# Debian include-binaries format

Tags: debian-packaging

I am trying to build a precompiled debian package for my application.
Some binaries (compiled modules) are present in my package.
Right now, I get an error with the message to add the binaries to debian/source/include-binaries

My problem is that I do not find anything about the format how to add it?

Right now I am using the command

```
debuild -us -uc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of this file is quite simple. You just have to specify the path of the binary, and this path has to be relative to the root of the package. You can specify only one binary per line. [Here is an example](http://sources.debian.net/src/libxml-parser-perl/2.41-1/debian/source/include-binaries) of this file that I've taken from `libxml-parser-perl` package:

```
debian/encodings/x-sjis-unicode.enc
debian/encodings/iso-8859-7.enc
debian/encodings/big5.enc
debian/encodings/x-sjis-cp932.enc
debian/encodings/iso-8859-9.enc
```

Comment: The debian packing situation is pure insanity. I can't believe this distro is as successful as it is. How is it that `include-binaries` doesn't even appear in https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/maint-guide.en.pdf ?!?!?!

Comment: The file and its format is described in the [dpkg-source man page](https://manpages.debian.org/dpkg-source#debian/source/include-binaries).